# Dynamic Dropdown based on Radio Button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a radio button that populated based on my one of my table in my database.

```
<?php 
    $query = "Select * from tbldenomination where productID = $id and status = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $denoID=$row["ID"];
        $deno=$row["denomination"];
        $price=$row["price"];
        $productCat=$row["productID"];      
        if ($productCat == 13) {
          ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="lblDeno">
              <input type="radio" required="true" name="price" value=<?php echo "$price"; ?> >
              <h5 class="h5"><?php echo"$deno"?></h5>
            </label>
          </div>
          <?php 
        }
        else{
         ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="lblDeno">
              <input type="radio" required="true" name="price" value=<?php echo "$price"; ?> >
              <h4><?php echo"$deno"?></h4>
            </label>
          </div>
        <?php 
        }
      }
    }
     ?>
```

And on the same table, there is a field for quantity. I want to create dynamic dropdown that will show the quantity based on the clicked radio button . How can I do it?

```
<select name="quantity"></select>
```

Comment: you use `ajax` for that

Comment: Thanks man! I made it